# When using select2, is there a way to get the 'select2:select' option to fire if there is a single item in the list?

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a dynamically populated list that I want a user to select an option from. Everything works as expected, unless there is only a single option in the list. I still want the 'select' event to fire even if it is the only option.

This is a simple codepen example of what I mean: http://codepen.io/user5754/pen/MJWWWd

```js
$(".exampleSelect").select2()
.on('select2:select', function (e) {
  alert('fire');
})
```

```css
.exampleSelect {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="exampleSelect">
  <option value="test">Want event to fire</option>
  <!--<option value="test2">Will fire if uncomment this</option> -->
</select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: *when* do you want the event to fire?

Comment: Whenever the user clicks on an option, regardless of if it's the only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a blank option, and then make sure you have some kind of validation to make sure the user doesn't do something that requires an option, if they haven't selected one yet.

```
<select class="exampleSelect">
  <option></option>
  <option value="test">Want event to fire</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the blank row, but if there are no other options...

Thanks!